# how to extract a substring in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following string in bash with length > 4

```
str = "abcdefghijklmno"
```

and I want to extract into `str2` the 5 first charachter of `str`. So

```
str2="abcde"
```

How to do it with bash?

Comment: you can do `man bash` to see command listing for this type of stuff

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Do use the expression

```
{string:position:length}
```

So in this case:

```
$ str="abcdefghijklm"
$ echo "${str:0:5}"
abcde
```

See other usages:

```
$ echo "${str:0}"      # default: start from the 0th position
abcdefghijklm
$ echo "${str:1:5}"    # start from the 1th and get 5 characters
bcdef
$ echo "${str:10:1}"   # start from 10th just one character
k
$ echo "${str:5}"      # start from 5th until the end
fghijklm
```

Taken from:
- [wooledge.org - How can I use parameter expansion? How can I get substrings? How can I get a file without its extension, or get just a file's extension?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)
- [Shell Command Language - 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Comment: +1 for without "external" command usage. :)  it would be better, to put the result into `str2`, as OP wished.

Comment: It's the right answer, but I'd suggest a different reference -- the ABS is considered a source of bugs, not wisdom, by freenode's #bash. Consider http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Comment: When I try this, I get the wrong answer arg=$1
echo "arg is $arg"
nm="${arg:0,5}"  
echo "name is: $nm"
arg is abcdefghijklmnop
name is: fghijklmnop

Comment: @slashdottir note you are using `${arg:0,5}` (note the comma) while I was using `${arg:0:5}` (colon).

Comment: To remove last 4 characters, `echo ${f:0:-4}`